# What are all the options that are set in the copper to coap server using block1 transfer?

Tags: python-2.7, coap

I am using the coap, copper, txthings as described in this turtoriall [https://www.win.tue.nl/~lrahman/iot_2016/tutorial/txThings_2016.pdf](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Elrahman/iot_2016/tutorial/txThings_2016.pdf).

Everything is setup and working well but I can't understand what one of the options refer to, my packet is as follows,

```
  x03\x02H\xb5other\x05block\x10\xb1\x06A\xe6\xff
```

My query is regarding 'x10' and x06A.  I know 'A' ascii-code is 0x41 and /xb1 is the block1 option and /xe6 is the NUM|M|SZX bits.

*Update*
part answer:-

```
x03\x02H\xb5other\x05block\x10\xb1\x06A\xe6\xff
```

My dump corresponds to the following hex values:-

```
0x03,0x02,0x48,0xb5 other 0x05, block, 0x10,0xb1,0x06,0x41,0xe6,payload_marker
```

I.e. an array of bytes where 'other' and 'block' are shown as strings for convenience.

Edited

Comment: That's defined in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7959. I'm not sure, if I really understand your dump. Is it possible that you use wireshark/tcpdump to capture it? Just for the case you're not common to capturing https://github.com/eclipse/californium/wiki/Logs-and-IP-Capturing-%E2%80%90-How-To-Provide-The-Right-Information.

Comment: I have nearly figured it out now, just the 0x10 to go...

Comment: In my experience, it's  much easier to use wireshark. Anyway, if you think it's worth, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7252 contains the other part to understand the coap-message encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints for the parts I understand:

> 0xb5 other 0x05, block

1. Option 11, len=5, Uri-Path, value "other" (RFC 7252)
2. Option 11, len=5, Uri-Path, value "block" (RFC 7252)

> 0x10

Option 12, len=0, Content-Format, value 0 (RFC 7252)

> 0xb1,0x06

Option 23, len=1, Block1, value 0x06 (num=0,m=false,szx=6/1024 bytes) (RFC 7959)

> 0x41,0xe6

Option 27, len=1, Block2, value 0xe6 (num=14,m=false,szx=6/1024 bytes) (RFC 7959)

Comment: Just to note block2=23, block1=27 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7959

Comment: The general encoding rules for options are in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7252#section-3.1. The first byte is split into two nibbles, the first indocates the delta for the option number, the second for the option length. Therefore 0x05 decodes into same option (11 Uri-Path), length 5. Read the specs, and you will get more insights. And try out wireshark :-).